# Setting a Forms ClientSize changes the Location of the control

Tags: .net, c++, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am resetting the size of a Form in a Control derived from Panel in the OnLayout handler after changing the control's size.

```
panel->ClientSize = size;
this->Parent->ClientSize = 
    System::Drawing::Size(
        this->Parent->ClientSize.Width, 
        this->Parent->ClientSize.Height-difference);
```

Stepping through the code with the debugger shows that the change in location happens when the Form's ClientSize is changed.  **The Panel is NOT Anchored to the Form.**

The problem I'm having is that this causes the controls location to change.

```
>>> FormPanel::layoutPanel - {X=604,Y=0}{Width=766, Height=250}
FormPanel::layoutPanel Height set - {X=604,Y=0}{Width=766, Height=217}
FormPanel - OnSizeChanged:{X=604,Y=0}{Width=766, Height=217}
FormPanel - OnLocationChanged:{X=604,Y=-17}{Width=766, Height=217}
FormPanel - OnMove:{X=604,Y=-17}{Width=766, Height=217}
Setting Form1->ClientSize = {Width=1370, Height=217}
<<< FormPanel::layoutPanel - {X=604,Y=-17}{Width=766, Height=217}
```

I get two events and the control has moved to Y = -17.

The questions I have are:

1) What is the difference between OnLocationChanged and OnMove?

2) Why has it moved?

3) Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: The LayoutEngine isn't going to expect a child control to change its parent, you're kinda on your own there.

Comment: It doesn't need to move the control though.

Comment: Hmmm, I think I see what you mean.  There are all sorts of strange effects.  Off to invent plan B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check to see how the control is anchored to it's parent.

Comment: As I said, the control is NOT anchored at all.

Comment: Sorry about that, you are right, it does need to be anchored.